# Issue involving bookmarks and newcommand with optional argument

Tags: macros, hyperref, bookmarks, optional-arguments

### Why results of an optional argument don't appear at bookmarks?

I was writing a text using some commands to insert formatted text. At some moment I added an optional argument and then I realized that the optional command result doesn't appear at the bookmark of the PDF, although it still appears at the table of contents.

I filtered the scenario into three simple cases of analysis:

- `\foo` is just a simple `newcommand` and works fine.
- `\bla` has a mandatory argument and works fine.
- `\cmd` has only an optional argument and doesn't appear at the bookmark list, nevertheless "`[v]`" used as optional argument is still presented at the bookmark.

The following MWE reproduces the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\foo}{A}
\newcommand{\bla}[1]{B{#1}}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1][]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{{\foo} -- {\bla{s}} -- {\cmd} -- {\cmd[v]}}
\end{document}
```

As seen at the image, the results of `\cmd` appears at title and `\tableofcontents`, but not at the bookmarks on the PDF.

[image]

Comment: Commands with optional arguments defined with `\newcommand` don't work in bookmarks.  Try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead, or define a suitable replacement in `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`.

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik. This command is from the package `xparse`. I tried `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` but could not understand how to use only one optional argument -- indeed, on of the six requirements say the last argument must be an mandatory argument. I only could use one single optional argument with the standard `\NewDocumentCommand`, but this doesn't show at bookmarks. I will still chck about ´\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`.

Comment: Basically, you can't have a single optional argument + bookmarks (a single optional argument only works with looking ahead (`\@ifnextchar`), and looking ahead is not expandable, thus no bookmarks).  `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` allows optional arguments without looking ahead, but requires a final mandatory argument (if it didn't require, you could get mysterious errors if the optional argument were missing).  With `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` you can define your command to either _require_ the optional argument, or ignore it, but not be _actually_ optional.  You're in a tough spot :)

Comment: Understood. I downgraded the command to a version without the optional argument, since the bookmark appearance was more important than the flexibility given from the option. Although this finding was unexpected, I must say it was interesting to learn it and to avoid this issue in the future. Thanks.